# Positioning for CSS smartphone mockup animation

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to do simple animation with css **slidein**. It suppose to imitate android screenshots sliding on phone screen.

CSS

```css
.phone {
 background: url("https://github.com/wojstu/CookingConnection/blob/4ee14ba85cb82dbfe803003d490a9c00705a0664/assets/images/dummie.png?raw=true") no-repeat;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 326px;
 height: 600px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0px auto;
 top: 50px;
 z-index: 1;
 
}
.screens {
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
 -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-name: slidein;
 z-index: 3;
 
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
 from {
  margin-left: 100%;
  
 }
 to {margin-left: 0%;
  
 }
}
@keyframes slidein {
 from {
  margin-left: 100%;
  
 }
 to {margin-left: 0%;
  
 }
}


img:nth-child(5){-webkit-animation-delay:0s;animation-delay:0s; z-index: 3}
img:nth-child(4){-webkit-animation-delay:4s;animation-delay:4s;z-index: 3}
img:nth-child(3){-webkit-animation-delay:8s;animation-delay:8s;z-index: 3}
img:nth-child(2){-webkit-animation-delay:12s;animation-delay:12s;z-index: 3}
img:nth-child(1){-webkit-animation-delay:16s;animation-delay:16s;z-index: 3}
.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 278px;
 height: 100%;
 border-top: 54px solid red;
 border-left: 24px solid red;
 border-right: 24px solid red;
 z-index: 2;
}
.hug {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 670px;
  margin: 0;
  
}

HTML
```

```html
<div class="hug">
  <div class="phone">
     <div class="container">
       <img class="screens" src="https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/2/AAC0izdgVVhy4roLbIoBFpxnqY7zP-Fxqq4D8c8juTEvlA/12/230572008/png/1024x768/3/1424178000/0/2/1.png/COj_-G0gASACIAMoASgC/SCXUOHO1qm4114kk-50_B6i80denUQ2TC2YrV5Q83tQ" alt="android app screen recipes">
       <img class="screens" src="https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAzqAwwCgdn0-B0tstddE0ueqjYzqx-PfWLE79LyoDbLQ/12/230572008/png/1024x768/3/1424178000/0/2/2.png/COj_-G0gASACIAMoASgC/NRZlT8kh2xyq71IsnL6PEQ7LWsd2tBftLLT4o_-fIBA" alt="android app screen overview">
       <img class="screens" src="https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/2/AAC0izdgVVhy4roLbIoBFpxnqY7zP-Fxqq4D8c8juTEvlA/12/230572008/png/1024x768/3/1424178000/0/2/1.png/COj_-G0gASACIAMoASgC/SCXUOHO1qm4114kk-50_B6i80denUQ2TC2YrV5Q83tQ" alt="android app screen ingridients">
       <img class="screens" src="https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAzqAwwCgdn0-B0tstddE0ueqjYzqx-PfWLE79LyoDbLQ/12/230572008/png/1024x768/3/1424178000/0/2/2.png/COj_-G0gASACIAMoASgC/NRZlT8kh2xyq71IsnL6PEQ7LWsd2tBftLLT4o_-fIBA" alt="android app screen recipe">
       <img class="screens" src="https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/2/AAC0izdgVVhy4roLbIoBFpxnqY7zP-Fxqq4D8c8juTEvlA/12/230572008/png/1024x768/3/1424178000/0/2/1.png/COj_-G0gASACIAMoASgC/SCXUOHO1qm4114kk-50_B6i80denUQ2TC2YrV5Q83tQ" alt="android app screen steps">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvLoVJ

so I wanted to have my parent div "phone" with transparent phone photo in front then "container" which would hide the screenshots outside the phone and finally images below everything else but I can't make it work with z-index.

Any hints?

Many thanks,
W

Answer (score 1):

OK so I was able to sort it out on my own:D It turns out that I needed to organized the order of elements via z-index and use negative values to do so.

Here's the fix, maybe someone'll find it useful.

**CSS**

```css
.phone {
  background: url("https://github.com/wojstu/CookingConnection/blob/4ee14ba85cb82dbfe803003d490a9c00705a0664/assets/images/dummie.png?raw=true") no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 326px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto;
  top: 50px;
}
.screens {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: 0.001%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: 0.001%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
img:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  z-index: -1;
}
img:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  z-index: -1;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
  animation-delay: 10s;
  z-index: -1;
}
img:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-delay: 15s;
  z-index: -1;
}
img:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
  animation-delay: 20s;
  z-index: -1;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 278px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 54px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hug">
  <div class="phone">
    <div class="container">
      <img class="screens" src="https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/2/AAC0izdgVVhy4roLbIoBFpxnqY7zP-Fxqq4D8c8juTEvlA/12/230572008/png/1024x768/3/1424178000/0/2/1.png/COj_-G0gASACIAMoASgC/SCXUOHO1qm4114kk-50_B6i80denUQ2TC2YrV5Q83tQ" alt="android app screen recipes">
      <img class="screens" src="https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAzqAwwCgdn0-B0tstddE0ueqjYzqx-PfWLE79LyoDbLQ/12/230572008/png/1024x768/3/1424178000/0/2/2.png/COj_-G0gASACIAMoASgC/NRZlT8kh2xyq71IsnL6PEQ7LWsd2tBftLLT4o_-fIBA" alt="android app screen overview">
      <img class="screens" src="https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/2/AAC0izdgVVhy4roLbIoBFpxnqY7zP-Fxqq4D8c8juTEvlA/12/230572008/png/1024x768/3/1424178000/0/2/1.png/COj_-G0gASACIAMoASgC/SCXUOHO1qm4114kk-50_B6i80denUQ2TC2YrV5Q83tQ" alt="android app screen ingridients">
      <img class="screens" src="https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAzqAwwCgdn0-B0tstddE0ueqjYzqx-PfWLE79LyoDbLQ/12/230572008/png/1024x768/3/1424178000/0/2/2.png/COj_-G0gASACIAMoASgC/NRZlT8kh2xyq71IsnL6PEQ7LWsd2tBftLLT4o_-fIBA" alt="android app screen recipe">
      <img class="screens" src="https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/2/AAC0izdgVVhy4roLbIoBFpxnqY7zP-Fxqq4D8c8juTEvlA/12/230572008/png/1024x768/3/1424178000/0/2/1.png/COj_-G0gASACIAMoASgC/SCXUOHO1qm4114kk-50_B6i80denUQ2TC2YrV5Q83tQ" alt="android app screen steps">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```